# Socket connection to remote host not being forwarded to k8s pod

Tags: sockets, kubernetes, remote-access, portforwarding

I have a remote host 1.2.3.4. I am opening a socket connection to the host with this statement -

```
Socket socket = new Socket("1.2.3.4", 2008);
```

And then I am sending a message using this statement -

```
String message = "Hello, remote machine!";
socket.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes());
```

Without port-forwarding any k8 pod, using the command -

```
nc -l 2008
```

I am able to receive the message `Hello, remote machine!`. But When I port-forward a k8 pod named test-pod like so -

```
kubectl port-forward test-pod 2008:2008
```

I get an error at this statement `Socket socket = new Socket("1.2.3.4", 2008);` saying `Connection refused`.

Its not clear why this is happening. There is a another service inside the test-pod that is accepting requests at the port 2008 as well. Where is the error?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `127.0.0.` after port-forwarding instead of `1.2.3.4`?